# Android :: retrieving data from sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, smsmanager

I have created a database with a table name CONTACTS and their i have two attributes (name,number) .. My job is to send message to that save emergency numbers ..

Problem is that I can't retrieve that values or numbers from that Contacts table where i can send the messages  ..

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(" NUMBER " , null, " TEXT ", null, null);
```

Here  I have to give the saved numbers present in the contact table ...

Comment: Check this link : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

try this if you have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper create a method inside it like this:

```
public Cursor getQueryCursor(String Query)
{
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);    
return c;   
}
```

and use it like this:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

Cursor c = dbHelper.getQueryCursor("SELECT * FROM CONTACTS");   
if (c != null ) {
if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
do {        
String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"));

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, " TEXT ", null, null);       
}while (c.moveToNext());
}
}
```